# Is it possible to get list of my podcast subscriptions using iTunes search API?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, itunes

I'm wondering if it's possible to get back a list of objects for each of my podcast subscriptions using the iTunes search API. I tried using my email/username for iTunes using the

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id={{my iTunes username}}&entity=podcast
```

but it looks like it needs a numerical value for the id which I'm unable to find for my account.